# How to get notified when a record is added or updated in database table in asp.net c# mvc codefirst approach application with ms sql server database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I have developed a basic application in asp.net MVC using codefirst approach, It has a basic model as follows:

```
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public DateTime Expected_Date_of_Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime Expected_Date_of_End { get; set; }
 }
```

I can insert, update, delete entities and all functionalities are working properly.
Now I want to get notified when someone inserts a new record or updates an existing one.

Just to clear the picture, I want to somehow build a notification system like the way facebook or twitter notifies their users on any changes that occurs.

How can I implement such a thing using asp.net mvc codefirst approach with c# language?

Comment: you can use SignalR with or without sqlEventHandler

Comment: Any reference for how to integrate signalr with codefirst?

Comment: using codefirst doesn't matter, you just need to call the signalr function on each insert or update or delete https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR

Comment: alternatively you can use `service broker` functionality of SQL, just google it to find the implementation way and samples

Comment: You could use SignalR as other suggested. the other choice is to use notification hub of azure(if you hosted on the cloud and using Azure services). 
You can also look into Kafka (generally used at huge level with support for many other things), Azure service bus with the azure function may be.

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to catch table modification event. As you wrote about EF CodeFirst I recommend to override SaveChanges. Something like this:

```
Public Overrides Function SaveChanges() As Integer
   For Each changedEntity In Me.ChangeTracker.Entries
       Select Case If(changedEntity.Entity.GetType.Namespace = "System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies", changedEntity.Entity.GetType.BaseType, changedEntity.Entity.GetType)
           Case GetType(YourEntityType)
               If changedEntity.State = EntityState.Added OrElse changedEntity.State = EntityState.Modified OrElse changedEntity.State = EntityState.Deleted Then
                  NotifyUser(changedEntity)
               End If
       End Select
   Next 
End Function
```

Then you need to notify user about this event (NotifyUser function). For that you may use SignalR or something else as @Elyas Esna & @Girish wrote.